# iPhone Dev: Create own index

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indexing

I currently got two problems I, both about the index of a UITableView

1. I want to change the color of some section-tags in the index, to show that there are new changes within this section.
2. I need to position the index on the left side of the table so it doesn't interfere with the detail disclosure Button

Is there a way to realize this with the standard-index? And if not, is it possible with a custom index? How would I realize such a thing and would apple tolerate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change color of index's rows. It is also impossible to move index to the left. But you can use TableViev's content offset property to narrow cells so index won't interfere with detail disclosure Button.

Comment: Or you can put second thin TableView to the left which will have only your index.