# How to change color of letters of sectionIndexTitlesForTableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need  to change the color of sectionIndexTitlesForTableView in iOS 5. I could not find any method in the APIs to do the task. Can anyone offer me some help?

The sectionIndexTitlesForTableView means the vertical bar in right hand side to show the the titles for the sections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think there is no documented way to customize your index.

Try to take a look to these Q&A:

[sectioned tableview index selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304548/sectioned-tableview-index-selection-highlighting)

[How do I change the color of the side Alphabet in an indexed UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-side-alphabet-in-an-indexed-uitableview)

Comment: To Downvoter -> Do you realize that this was asked in 2012? And that now we have different tools? Good...

Answer (score 25):

Go to the IB and change the text COLOR to white, Works for me[image]

//=========================================

And in Swift, you can also change Programatically by:

```
self.my_tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: This is working for me as well - this should be the correct answer.

Comment: The question was asked in 2012 and it is related to iOS 5!! This is the correct answer NOW that tools changed.

Comment: @Beppe I understand It. Even If some don't. I faced this thing in 2013. So I posted accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Following code is a straight solution.  api is available from iOS 6

```
 [tableView setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

you can just set the:

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor
```

to whatever color your want like:

```
tableView.sectionIndexColor = .red
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.0**

The code line below will change the font color of the section index on table view. I have attached the resulting screenshot of the implementation.

```
self.tblYourTableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    for(UIView *view in [tableView subviews])
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
        {
        [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }



    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

//***Table cell create

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Write Bellow code in your viewDidLoad (for swift)**

tableName.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the section index colors by changing the tintColor of the tableView.

```
tableView.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: works! this or answer from @ricks should be marked as proper as: tableView.sectionIndexColor = .red